# Apache Camel Route Multicast does not copy the exchange message

Tags: copy, apache-camel, multicast

i made a `camel route` in my application with `spring dsl`.I want to copy the `exchange body` with using `multicast` EIP.But when i use this, i can take the `exchange body`from one of my `endpoint`.In the second one (which is endpoint in multicast ) ,the exchange body is `null`.Why this is happening like this?

**EDIT**
This is my route:

```
<route errorHandlerRef="dlc1" id="mobitRoute1">

            <from uri="cxf:bean:mobit-okuma?dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />
            <wireTap uri="activemq:queue:anaMobitQueue" />
            <to uri="velocity:response.vm" />

        </route>

        <route id="mobitRoute2" errorHandlerRef="dlc2">

            <from uri="activemq:queue:anaMobitQueue" />
            <unmarshal ref="myJaxb" />
            <to uri="bean:timeChanging" />
            <multicast>

                <to uri="activemq:queue:mobitOkumaq" />
                <to uri="activemq:queue:AysMobit" />

            </multicast>
        </route>

        <route errorHandlerRef="dlc3" id="mobitRoute3">

            <from uri="activemq:queue:AysMobit" />
            <!-- <unmarshal ref="myJaxb" /> -->
            <to uri="bean:fromPayload" />
            <to uri="cxf:bean:ays-service?dataFormat=POJO" />

        </route>

        <route errorHandlerRef="dlc4" id="mobitRoute4">

            <from uri="activemq:queue:mobitOkumaq" />
            <to uri="cxf:bean:mobit-okumaReal?dataFormat=POJO" />

        </route>
```

Comment: Could you share the route you have configured?

Comment: I added the route by editing the question @Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by transforming xml when i put the exchange to the queue.This is why ? I don't know.

```
<route errorHandlerRef="dlc1" id="mobitRoute1">

            <from uri="cxf:bean:mobit-okuma?dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />

            <wireTap uri="activemq:queue:anaMobitQueue" />
            <to uri="velocity:response.vm" />

        </route>

        <route errorHandlerRef="dlc1" id="mobitRoute2">
            <from uri="activemq:queue:anaMobitQueue" />

            <camel:pipeline>
                <unmarshal ref="myJaxb" />
                <to uri="bean:timeChanging" />
                <!-- <to uri="direct:unmarshalled"/> -->
                <marshal ref="myJaxb" />
                <camel:multicast>

                    <to uri="activemq:queue:BegisMobit" />
                    <to uri="activemq:queue:AysMobit" />

                </camel:multicast>
            </camel:pipeline>

        </route>



        <route errorHandlerRef="dlc2" id="mobitRoute3">

            <from uri="activemq:queue:AysMobit" />
            <unmarshal ref="myJaxb" />
            <to uri="bean:fromPayload" />
            <to uri="cxf:bean:ays-service?dataFormat=POJO" />

        </route>

        <route errorHandlerRef="dlc3" id="mobitRoute4">

            <from uri="activemq:queue:BegisMobit" />
            <unmarshal ref="myJaxb" />
            <to uri="cxf:bean:mobit-okumaReal?dataFormat=POJO" />

        </route>
```